# Design: ORM and Application Layers

Tags: asp.net, orm, architecture

While designing (and then implementing) a layered application:

Is it correct to use the same ORM objects accross all layers? (which would go against encapsulation).

Or the presentation, business and data layer should each have their own objects? (which would lead to lots of code repetition).

e.g. (just to illustrate the question): if one uses Linq to SQL in the Data Layer and Visual Studio's O/R designer to generate the ORM objects, are those objects supposed to be used in the Business and Presentation Layers as well.

i.e.: **Are the objects associated with the entities that the application handles a crosscutting issue?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends by your business. if you are talking about a small application you could do it. 
Usually the best practices wants to don't expose the entity from the DAL to the presentation because doing that the layer are going to be tightly coupled and you could expose data that doesn't make sense at the top layer (presentation)
on the other hand you shouldn’t create a bunch of object per each layer.
it's always hard answer this question because it really depends by your needs.
you can have a look at this book just to have an idea about

http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=FyWZt5DdvFkC&printsec=frontcover&dq=martin+fowler+enterprise+architecture&source=bl&ots=eEEx4ATr5C&sig=sSmDmffOSALWfFZEaPyhkwwEq_I&hl=en&ei=SJnSTMuSJIHm4AaK9tW5Dw&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CDAQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q&f=false

Comment: +1 - only I'm probably of a firmer view that it's not a good idea.